# #Nitrous : You are using more storage than the requested amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, space, disk

I have removed several try-outs from apps. I had to restart the box a couple of times...

Nitrous is a fine way to learn Ruby On Rails, but even with an empty Nitrous folder, the program says that I have no space left to start another new app.

What must I do to remove all data on the serverside of Nitrous?

Sorry, the tag "nitrous" wasn't allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate the app from the dashboard, and then create a new one.